# How to make two object collide in cocos 2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

```
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(projectileRect, targetRects))
        {
           NSLog(@"ha ha Collision detected");
        }

     CGRect projectileRect = [player boundingBox];
     CGRect targetRects = [anEnemy boundingBox];
```

This is the code i am using for collision.The problem is many time the collision get not checked.If it get checked the position of collision is bottom left or right.

PLease advise what to do or any sample of how to do collision.ALso i am not using box or chimpunk

Comment: Make sure you are calling this from the **update** function.  Also check frame rate,  sometimes if the frame rate is very low like 20 FPS or lower there can be be misses like you describe.

Comment: I am calling this in in accelerometer update method.Since my object move left or right with device acceleration..
But your point seems to be legit but my frames are not even dropping.But i can seems  to be able to find a solution yet

Can you help me in explaining if something needed in my player sprite to get intersect with enemy sprite.which i might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check if the object has passed through the object as well. Ray has some great tuts on all of this [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone)

Comment: The link you send is for box2d.I mention that  in my game i am not using anything else simple cocos 2d.Please advise something else

Comment: Please browse Ray's site. It is full of Cocos2d information, not just one link. You will need to do some research rather than look for an exact answer to your question in order to actually understand how Cocos2d functions.

Comment: Hi..i make the collision worked the problem seems to in declaring my enemy sprite.
Also after research i came here and every one is aware of Ray...

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. ;-)